# Can a Recommendation System Model (DNN) be converted in Tensorflow Lite for Mobile Device Inference?

Tags: mobile, device, tensorflow2.0, recommendation-engine, tensorflow-lite

I am working on a personal project and new to TFLite. Is it possible to convert a DNN (similar to https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/recommendation/) be converted by TFLite for mobile devices? I am using TF2.0

What should i be watching for?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: An example would be the recommender system from google colab https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/eng-edu/blob/master/ml/recommendation-systems/recommendation-systems.ipynb?utm_source=ss-recommendation-systems&utm_campaign=colab-external&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=recommendation-systems

Comment: Please let us know what you tried so far, and what problem you have. In theory it should work!

Comment: Thank @adrisons and rmeertens, i will keep you posted.